# cronjob not working hourly

Tags: cron, cron-task

If I schedule my cronjob to work with minutes (*, */5 etc) the cronjob is executing. Working with hours, the cronjob doesnt seem to work.

This is my list of cronjobs:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script/ swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
* * * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
0 0 * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
*/3 * * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
0 0 * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
0 0 * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
0 0 * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
```

The ones at midnight are not running. If I change

```
*/3 * * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
```

to

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script >> /path/to/cron.log 2>&1
```

that particular script will also stop running.

If I set all the scripts to run every minute, there are no errors in the cron.log.

how is this possible?

Comment: What are the errors in cron.log? @adfz

Comment: as mentioned in the question there are no errors in the log.